# Android Signalr - Send request to server

Tags: android, signalr.client

Im researching on Android Signalr. How can I send api url (ex: http://testside.com/api/userid=1) from java client-side to server and get return json data on event hub.on()? Thanks in advance. :D

Comment: Sadly, topics like this are not supported in StackOverflow, for more details look at our [on-topic guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Hi, I solved my problem. Thanks :D